# Best way to split up an array of flat records (hashes) to normalized hashes based on key suffix?

Tags: ruby

What is the best (most performant) way to turn:

```
csv_data = [
  {'id' => 1, 'foo_1' => 'a', 'bar_1' => 'b', 'foo_2' => 'c', 'bar_2' => 'd'},
  {'id' => 2, 'foo_1' => 'e', 'bar_1' => 'f', 'foo_2' => 'g', 'bar_2' => 'h'}
]
```

to

```
records = [
  {'id' => 1, 'foo' => 'a', 'bar' => 'b'},
  {'id' => 1, 'foo' => 'c', 'bar' => 'd'},
  {'id' => 2, 'foo' => 'e', 'bar' => 'f'},
  {'id' => 2, 'foo' => 'g', 'bar' => 'h'}
]
```

Clarification: there could be foo_1 all the way to foo_100, but it varies.

Comment: Do you always have 2 elements foo/bar in the input csv data? Do they have always have the same name? with this single example is hard to deduce how generic the algorithm should be. If the real case is more complex, paste an input that shows this complexity.

Comment: There are the same 20ish different columns for each suffix that gets repeated. So, yes.

Comment: The most performant way is to _not_ create the `csv_data` array and to create your desired output directly while parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had always the same keys with length 2, you could write:

```
records = csv_data.flat_map do |row|
  [
    {id: row["id"], foo: row["foo_1"], bar: row["bar_1"]},
    {id: row["id"], foo: row["foo_2"], bar: row["bar_2"]},
  ]
end
```

A more generic algorithm that works for any fields and length. I'll add the data at each step, it may help:

```
records = csv_data.flat_map do |row|
  row
    # {"id"=>1, "foo_1"=>"a", "bar_1"=>"b", "foo_2"=>"c", "bar_2"=>"d"}
    .reject { |key, value| key == "id" }
    # {"foo_1"=>"a", "bar_1"=>"b", "foo_2"=>"c", "bar_2"=>"d"}
    .group_by { |key, value| key.split("_")[0] }
    # {"foo"=>[["foo_1", "a"], ["foo_2", "c"]], "bar"=>[["bar_1", "b"], ["bar_2", "d"]]}
    .map { |tag, key_values| [tag].product(key_values.map(&:last)) } 
    # [[["foo", "a"], ["foo", "c"]], [["bar", "b"], ["bar", "d"]]]
    .transpose
    # [[["foo", "a"], ["bar", "b"]], [["foo", "c"], ["bar", "d"]]]
    .map { |pairs| {"id" => row["id"]}.merge(pairs.to_h) }
    # [{"id"=>1, "foo"=>"a", "bar"=>"b"}, {"id"=>1, "foo"=>"c", "bar"=>"d"}]
end
```

Comment: I do have variable amount of suffix though. So it could go from foo_1 to foo_100.

Comment: I think this just might work. Will mark answered after some testing Thank you so much! I do think your original thought was correct too: since I have the columns I can just grab the last key's number and use that `number.times` to iterate through like your first answer.

Comment: Yes, getting the last index and iterating over the data is the other way. It's a bit less elegant (subjective) but the code is simpler.